# EF 4.3 Inheritance using the existing base

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4

i have a base entity UserBase(UserId,Username). i created a child entity SecurityUser(Password). i have another child entity PortalUser(Name, Surname).

i create a new entity for SecurityUser and add it to context and savechanges.UserId is 1 for this user. i adds one line to both UserBase and SecurityUser tables.

how can i add new PortalUser for the same base user entity(UserId=1)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That is principle of inheritance. `User` can be either `SecurityUser` or `PortalUser` - it never can be both. If you need `User` to be both security and portal user you must user normal relation like `User` and `Role`.

Comment: do you mean only solution is to use navigation property for user?

Comment: Yes that is correct solution in situation where user can have more than one role or change roles.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: Is it possible to address a base class `Task` and derived classes that represent the state of the task such as queued, partially completed, completed, etc. I am thinking from a DB perspective where you could manage state efficiently by using grouping tables. In short, a base type will never be more than one derived type but would need to switch from one to the other.

Comment: Raheel: No EF doesn't support type switching.